# MySQL - Add a common WHERE condition to all queries at once.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I have set of sql queries already written and working fine in my website.

Now, i want to add 'where common condition clause' all of those queries.
I don't wanna re write all my queries with this additional condition, instead i like do something by which it automatically applies to all queries run on my database from now on.

Is there any such method to do this?

MY Data base: MYSQL

MY website: PHP, YII

Answer (score 2):

There may be a way to solve this problem using views.  Say you have queries of the form:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 . . .
```

And you now want:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 . . .
where t1.field = 'x'
```

You can solve this by doing the following steps:

1. Rename `table1` to something (say `_table1`):

   ```
   rename table table1 to _table1;
   ```
2. Create a view with the name `table1`:

   ```
   create view table1 as
   select *
   from _table1
   where field = 'x';
   ```

In general, I think it is a better idea to change existing queries (and views in MySQL can cause problems with optimization).  However, there are some circumstances where this approach might be appropriate for quickly getting the changes you need.

Comment: I have to do this yii. so, i cant change my database schema like that. bcoz, every time i change something in Database I have to build new Models again for each table.

Comment: You misunderstood Gordon's suggestion. The edits proposed are only on the db side and Yii is totally blind to it. Current models in Yii should work fine without any problem, because the model will be served by the new view from the db (which has the same name as previous table).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use a subquery. Say you have:

`select * from table1 where field1="banana"`

you can wrap this in a subquery

`select * from ([old query]) t_sub where fieldx='Y'`

so that you get

`select * from (select * from table1 where field1="banana") t_sub where fieldx='Y'`

However, you will need to reanalyze the queries / indexes because you are probably going to get a major performance hit.

As Gordon Linoff said, it is much better to redo the queries from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit limited. I don't know if you expect changes like this to occur more often. If not then simply change the queries and be done with it. If there are more changes expected you could make a simple table with "global variables" that you set up in the queries once. then you can maintain them for all queries simultaniously from then on.

simple example:

`SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (SELECT GlobalVar FROM VarTable)`

You could fancy it up from there with identifying your queries in the script and referring to this identity in the variables table. (a where in the subselect)

Anyway, hope this helps you a bit!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help you [THE DEFINITIVE GUIDE TO YII](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes).

**Default Scope**

A model class can have a default scope that would be applied for all queries (including relational ones) about the model. For example, a website supporting multiple languages may only want to display contents that are in the language the current user specifies. Because there may be many queries about the site contents, we can define a default scope to solve this problem. To do so, we override the CActiveRecord::defaultScope method as follows,

```
class Content extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function defaultScope()
    {
        return array(
            'condition'=>"language='".Yii::app()->language."'",
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be applicable if all queries are done through Active Records. SQL queries & ADO would be left behind as it was.